# Existential vs. universal alternation

Tags: logic, negation

Is there a difference between trivial and nontrivial negation? It occurred to me that we could think of the following series of negation operations/relations:

1. Empty negation = primordial double-negation elimination (DNE). Modulo (2), this can be construed as *empty alterity*.
2. Alterity = a kind of trivial negation = the "other than" relation, "*A* is other than *B*."
3. Inequivalence of absence and opposition/contrariety: ¬(¬*A* = *A*¬) (the occurrence of the negation sign on the right of *A*, there, mirrors the distinction between a modal operation **M***x* and another *x***M** (as when we prefix and/or suffix some "**M**" by "¬"). Might not be as trivial as (2).
4. The greater than/less than relation: more nontrivial, since incommensurable terms are logically possible. (See also e.g. [the SEP article on continuity and infinitesimals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuity/) for depictions of infinitesimals as neither larger nor smaller than zero, but not equal to zero, either.)
5. Whichever demi-negations we admit into our system.
6. Based on the conditions of (5) or not, all the inverse arithmetical operators of *n*th-order (or more) arithmetic, e.g. subtraction is traced back to complementation, and then both stand under division, which is below logarithms and roots, which are below the counterparts for tetration, and so on and on.

One of the SEP articles on contradictions or negation or dialethism (I don't remember which) mentions Graham Priest's objection that analyzing ordinary-language "not" as an incompatibility/incompossibility marker is to prejudge the linguistic situation in favor of the LNC, which in this dialectical context is in dispute. Now that might be a fair complaint on its own but it also seems as if we simply do have an incompatibility/incompossibility operation anyway, i.e. there are times when, "*A* and not *A*," must be false.

With that in mind, this is my question:

1. If we iterate the alterity operation, as in, "*A* is other than other-than-*B*," does DNE then hold trivially? It seems perhaps not, since:
2. If we differentiate existential from universal alternation, we seem to allow for a potentially false localization of DNE and a necessarily true one:
3. Letting "❧" mean "other than," take *A* = ❧❧<sub>∃</sub>*A*. This would be read as, "There exists an *A* that is other than other-than-*A*, which equals *A*." But this seems unnecessary (see below).
4. By contrast, *A* = ❧❧<sub>∀</sub>*A* seems (trivially) true, since if the given other-than-*A*'s are *all* the others-than-*A*, we are just left with *A* again.

Regarding (3), imagine starting with some *x* for the initial element in the set of finite ordinals and writing *x*' to signify something different from *x*, and substitute this signification process for the typical construction of Zermelo or von Neumann ordinals by then writing {*x*, *x*'}' to mark out the next number, and then {{*x*, *x*'}'}', and so on. But so again, if we are simply referring to different *x*'s, it doesn't then seem as though "other-than-other-than *x*" automatically refers back to just *x*, but could refer to something other than *x* and other than our initial example of something else besides *x*.

**Is DNE trivially true for universal alternation and nontrivially possibly false for existential alternation?**

---

**Revision: vertex-free hypergraphs as logical operations considered by themselves**

Assume that nodes in a logical graph represent propositions, with edges representing inference relations. But it is reportedly possible to imagine two free-floating edges that connect to each other without constituting a first-order node (although, on a second-order level, any system of edges, vertex-free or not, can be collapsed into a node). Let such a hypergraph then be a representation of a logical operation "by itself."

Interpretation: then this is the intuition that intuitionists have about DNE and proof-by-contradiction: if we use the cancellative type of "not," then if we write ¬¬*A* we should end up with *A*, yet why are we compelled to write down *A*? So then there is an even emptier alterity, if you will, than reported above, but there is the vertex-free hypergraph of two ¬-operations, the one acting on the other, which leaves behind no nodes *A*. So there is a dimension of pure negation which does not support DNE as useful for establishing affirmative propositions "after the fact."

Comment: Kristian, as interesting and engaging as this set of questions is, surely there comes a point at which you recognise that you’re reaching above what this platform provides? I can have a go at engaging in what I think will be of relevance both to you and the external reader, but I’m only going to be able to tackle a small fraction of what this poses, and even then it’s going to need a lot of supporting framing for the reader!

Comment: @PaulRoss yeah IDK what to do with this stuff. I've tried posting on philosophy subreddits since those seem more supportive of conjectural presentation, but they always seem to have the oddest problems with my posts (case-in-point, one of them was deleted for having too many parentheses!). I'm not skilled enough at actual math for the MathOverflow (I've tried my hand there, with uneasy results). It would be nice if they had a LogicOverflow, maybe...

Comment: I'm somewhat hopeful that someone here might be familiar with e.g. modern French schools/analysts of logic (like Beziau) that seem like they might have bearing on my questions, but which I've not studied much on my own time (I tried going through Alessio Moretti's technical sections for his "hyperflower theory" but my mind blanked out when he had huge stretches of the text consisting in lists of numbers or factors). There was a poster who showed up a while back who had a good answer to some other question (not mine), she brought up category theory in a really sophisticated way, then vanished.

Comment: Would you consider rephrasing your question in fewer words in plain language?

Comment: @MarcoOcram IDK, it seems like there are a lot of variables and it's nice to have specific terms/phrases for these across the board, I'm not sure of any "simpler" presentation (maybe when they refer to demi-negation as "the square root of NOT"?). The reasoning occurs as an attempt to find relative supports/"evidence" for intuitionism, paraconsistent logic, and classical logic together, if that helps.

Comment: Keep the questions coming dude, it’s motivating. Leave it up for as long as is needed. Eventually your answer will come, and victory will be sweet.

Comment: I usually have no idea what you're talking about, but it's usually thought provoking to try to parse what you have, so I'm with hmltn.